# Add an array to an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my code that I have tried.

```
List<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    arrList.add("a"+i);
    arrList.add("b"+i);
    arrList.add("c"+i);
}
model.addAttribute("arrList", arrList);
```

**This gives the output:** `[a0, b0, c0, a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3, a4, b4, c4]`

**Expected output:** [`[a0, b0, c0], [a1, b1, c1], [a2, b2, c2], [a3, b3, c3], [a4, b4, c4]]`

Comment: the expected output looks like a list of lists of strings

Comment: I'd expect your first output, but not your second.  You're only adding strings, not a list of strings.

Comment: `ArrayList` and array are two different things. If you want a list of lists, declare it as `List<List<String>>`. If you want arrays, declare it as `String[][]`.

Comment: You create a List<String> that stores String items and that's it. You aren't creating two arrays and storing the array contents in an array.

Comment: Side note: I might be picky here but array != list. Although you are using `ArrayList` which is a list but internally uses arrays to handle the list there's still a difference and thus you should keep the 2 apart. As an example, since you know you'll have 5 entries of 3 elements each using an array you could write `String[][] arr = new String[5][3];` (an array of arrays just as you seem to expect) and adapt the rest of your code accordingly.

Comment: Why do you expect that output?  When you print the values, what information does the system have which would group the values in the output like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `List<List<String>>` instead for example :

```
List<List<String>> arrList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    arr.add("a" + i);
    arr.add("b" + i);
    arr.add("c" + i);
    arrList.add(arr);
}
System.out.println(arrList);
```

**Output**

```
[[a0, b0, c0], [a1, b1, c1], [a2, b2, c2], [a3, b3, c3], [a4, b4, c4]]
```

Comment: Don't declare `arr` outside the loop. Also, you could use `arrList.add(Arrays.asList("a" + i, "b" + i, "c" + i))` for shorter code giving same result.

Comment: thank you @Andreas for the first one i take it for the second i think it is a little weird for the OP no?

Comment: Thanks @YCF_L for the help

Comment: you are welcome @irengba

Answer (score 2):

If you were trying to do this with pure arrays without using the List library:

```
 String[][] arr = new String[5][3];
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arr[i][0] = "a" + i;
    arr[i][1] = "b" + i;
    arr[i][2] = "c" + i;
 }
```

Then print as required.

Comment: You can also do `new String[5][]` and then `arr[i] = new String[] { "a" + i, "b" + i, "c" + i }` inside the loop.

Comment: Good shorthand! I like it!

Comment: Given the fallacies of printing arrays, perhaps showing how is better than "print as required"?

Comment: I edited my previous print statement because it looks like he is using a printing class that takes a String and a List object. I didn't want to confuse the guy with building a string when he already has a tool for that at this point.